# How to get elements between two tags Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

This is my Html

```
<b><font color="Red">Flash Player 720p HD Quality Online Links</font></b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://bestarticles.me/jaana-na-dil-se-door/?si=5325359" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video- Part 1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://bestarticles.me/jaana-na-dil-se-door/?si=5325360" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video- Part 2</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <b><font color="Red">Dailymotion 720p HD Quality Online Links</font></b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://bestarticles.me/jaana-na-dil-se-door/?si=k4r2rHPOgem8yAlGqjj" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video- Part 1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://bestarticles.me/jaana-na-dil-se-door/?si=k63MLC2Vq6fxsPlGqjp" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video- Part 2</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <b><font color="Red">TVLogy 720p HD Quality Online Links</font></b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://reviewtv.in/star-plus/?si=YD29025" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video- Part 1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://reviewtv.in/star-plus/?si=YD29026" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video- Part 2</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <b><font color="Red">Letwatch 720p HD Quality Online Links</font></b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.tellycolors.me/star-plus/?si=j3vpekz3jeiv" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video - Part 1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.tellycolors.me/star-plus/?si=bdjg53bz9gdi" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video - Part 2</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <b><font color="Red">Vidwatch 720p HD Quality Online Links</font></b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://hd-rulez.info/vidwatch.php?id=73sbn356g9nc" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video - Part 1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://hd-rulez.info/vidwatch.php?id=73x796cifyvq" target="_blank">Jaana Na Dil Se Door 6th February 2017 Watch Online Video - Part 2</a>
        <br>
        <br>
```

I am using Simple Html Dom php library for scrapping. I want to scrap `<b>` tags with their anchor tags. Every `<b>` elements have their `<a>` anchor set. so I want to scrap like this

```
array(
       'Flash Player' => array( 'link1', 'link2' ),
       'Daiylymotion' => array('link1', 'link2', 'link3'),
       etc...
);
```

And this is what I am doing. First I escaped all `<br>` tags then loop on all `<b>` tags then I am trying to get next siblings of `<b>` tag by $b->next_sibling() but its not working because by escaping `<br>` tags index of elements not updated. Here is my code

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
$content = $html->find('div.postcontent',0);

   //escape all br
    foreach($content->find('br') as $br){
        $br->outertext = '';
    }

    foreach($content->find('b') as $key => $b){


        echo $b->plaintext;

    }
```

Please help me by scrapping `<b>` with their `<a>` tags with another strategy. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any other easier methods. But this code will give your desired output as long as each `<b>` tag has exactly **two** `<a>` tags following.

```
    $aCount = 0;
    $result = array();
    foreach($content->find('b') as $key => $b){
        $index = $b->plaintext;  
        for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
            $result[$index][] = $content->find('a',$aCount++)->href;
        }       
    }  
    print_r($result);
```

The output will be like

```
Array
(
    [Flash Player 720p HD Quality Online Links] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://bestarticles.me/jaana-na-dil-se-door/?si=5325359
            [1] => http://bestarticles.me/jaana-na-dil-se-door/?si=5325360
        )

    [Dailymotion 720p HD Quality Online Links] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://bestarticles.me/jaana-na-dil-se-door/?si=k4r2rHPOgem8yAlGqjj
            [1] => http://bestarticles.me/jaana-na-dil-se-door/?si=k63MLC2Vq6fxsPlGqjp
        )

    [TVLogy 720p HD Quality Online Links] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://reviewtv.in/star-plus/?si=YD29025
            [1] => http://reviewtv.in/star-plus/?si=YD29026
        )

    [Letwatch 720p HD Quality Online Links] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.tellycolors.me/star-plus/?si=j3vpekz3jeiv
            [1] => http://www.tellycolors.me/star-plus/?si=bdjg53bz9gdi
        )

    [Vidwatch 720p HD Quality Online Links] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://hd-rulez.info/vidwatch.php?id=73sbn356g9nc
            [1] => http://hd-rulez.info/vidwatch.php?id=73x796cifyvq
        )

)
```